# Confused about Haskell number types

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a `foldr` example that converts an `Integral` to a list of digits (i.e., `[Int]`).

```
pickDigit num pos = (num `div` (10^pos)) `mod` 10

toDigits num = foldr (\pos acc -> (pickDigit num pos):acc) [] [0 .. floor (logBase 10 num)]
```

This loads successfully. But when I try to run it, for example

```
> toDigits 1234
```

I get a type error message I don't understand.

When I ask Haskell for the types of the loaded code and explicitly include those types in the source file, I get error messages on loading. When I try to explicitly restrict the types to `Integer` or `Int`, I get more error messages.

I'd appreciate some suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Please also post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`logBase` requires Floating, but it's not

This works:

```
[0 .. floor (logBase 10 $ fromIntegral num)]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But why doesn't this problem show up when the code loads? If there is no declaration in the source, the code loads fine.Then `:t toDigits` ->  `toDigits :: (RealFrac a, Integral a, Floating a) => a -> [a]`

Comment: Because there are no concrete types. It loads, because for some hypothetic type `a`, which is `Integral` and also `RealFrac` this function will work.

Comment: In addition to Alexander's comment, you call the function with `1234` as the argument, which has type `Num a => a`, where `a` could be the hypothetical type that has instances for both `Integral` and `RealFrac`.